# How to setup url rewriting for a website where dynamic links are inserted

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I am trying to make website where users are able to post content using an WYSIWYG editor. In my .htaccess file i have

```
 FallbackResource index.php
```

which is successfully sending all requests to the index.php file. I am then using PHP to require the desired file

```
$path = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
//[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => C:/xampp/htdocs/tests/index.php
if($path[2] == 'notifications'){
    require_once 'notifications.php';
}
```

All this works fine. The problem arises when i try to redirect to an external link like google.com. The link itself gets redirected to the index page instead of being redirected.
This is the key because users can insert tags for other websites as reference in their text with the WYSIWYG editors. So my question is, Am i doing this right or do i need a different approach? and if so, which approach?. I would greatly appreciate similar approaches to those used by sites like facebook or twitter.

Comment: How is an external link being internally redirected.  Are you accidentally changing that link to be internal?  what's this `In my .htaccess file i have FallbackResource index.php` can you share some of the .htaccess rules you use? Be sure to remove anything you don't want public like the host for example you could do `www.mysite.com` instead of the real name.

Comment: That tiny bit of PHP is ok, but an external request should never be processed internally as it would by definition call another server.  IE. you havn't given enough information to figure it out.

Comment: FallbackResource index.php is the only code i have in my .htaccess file which tells it to use or fallback to the index.php file. I want to hard code using PHP instead of using .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS for an approach I would use a method similar to CodeIgniter or other MVC frameworks ( but simpler ).

So first you have to devise a schema, what I mean by that is something like this

```
   www.yoursite.com/index.php/{controller}/{method}/args ...
```

Then you would build a router to go parse the url. I can write you one but it will take a minute.

**UPDATE**

You can find it on my github page [here](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Router)

But for refrence here is the code:

SimpleRouter.php

```
/**
 * A simple 1 level router
 * 
 * URL schema is http://example.com/{controller}/{method}/{args ... }
 * 
 * @author ArtisticPhoenix
 * @package SimpleRouter
 */
class SimpleRouter{

    /**
     * should be the same as rewrite base in .htaccess
     * @var string
     */
    const REWRITE_BASE = '/MISC/Router/';

    /**
     * path to controller files
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    const CONTOLLER_PATH = __DIR__.'/Controllers/';

    /**
     * route a url to a controller
     */
    public static function route(){
        //normalize
        if(self::REWRITE_BASE != '/'){
            $uri = preg_replace('~^'.self::REWRITE_BASE.'~i', '',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
        $uri = preg_replace('~^index\.php~i', '',$uri);      
        $uri = trim($uri,'/');

        //empty url, like www.example.com
        if(empty($uri)) $uri = 'home/index';

        //empty method like www.example.com/home
        if(!substr_count($uri, '/')) $uri .= '/index';

        $arrPath = explode('/', $uri);

        $contollerName = array_shift($arrPath);
        $methodName = array_shift($arrPath);;
        $contollerFile = self::CONTOLLER_PATH.$contollerName.'.php';

        if(!file_exists($contollerFile)){
            //send to error page
            self::error404($uri);
            return;
        }

        require_once $contollerFile;

        if(!class_exists($contollerName)){
            self::error404($uri);
            return;
        }

        $Controller = new $contollerName();

        if(!method_exists($Controller, $methodName)){
            self::error404($uri);
            return;
        }

        if(!count($arrPath)){
            call_user_func([$Controller, $methodName]);
        }else{
            call_user_func_array([$Controller, $methodName], $arrPath);
        } 
    }

    /**
     * call error 404
     * 
     * @param string $uri
     */
    protected static function error404($uri){
        require_once self::CONTOLLER_PATH.'home.php';     
        $Controller = new home();
        $Controller->error404($uri);
    }
}
```

Default Controller home.php

```
/**
 * 
 * The default controller
 * 
 * @author ArtisticPhoenix
 * @package SimpleRouter
 */
class home{

    public function index($arg=false){
        echo "<h3>".__METHOD__."</h3>";
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(func_get_args());
    }

    public function otherpage($arg){
        echo "<h3>".__METHOD__."</h3>";
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(func_get_args());
    }

    public function error404($uri){
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        echo "<h3>Error 404 page {$uri} not found</h3>";
    }

}
```

2nd Controller (example) user.php

```
/**
 *
 * An example users router
 *
 * @author ArtisticPhoenix
 * @package SimpleRouter
 */
class user{

    public function index(){
        echo "<h3>".__METHOD__."</h3>";
    }


    public function login(){
        echo "<h3>".__METHOD__."</h3>";
    }

}
```

Rewrite (remove index.php) .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On

# For sub-foder installs set your RewriteBase including trailing and leading slashes
# your rewrite base will vary, possibly even being / if no sub-foder are involved
RewriteBase /MISC/Router/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Finally index.php

```
require_once __DIR__.'/SimpleRouter.php';
SimpleRouter::route();
```

I went with a `static` call to the router just to keep things simple, this way no instance is needed of the class which only has 2 methods (1 public) anyway.

I built it as a single level router, what I mean by that is that you cannot put controllers in sub-folders, such as `Controllers/user/home.php` instead of just `Controllers/user.php`.  This should be fine for small to medium sized sites, but for a vary large site it may be desirable to nest the controllers.  However this adds a bunch of complexity to it.

The advantage of this way, instead of individually creating the routes should be obvious.  You shouldn't have to touch the code as long as the route (the url) follows the simple schema I outlined. This also allows you organize the sections of your site in their own files by functionality.  For example take the `user.php` controller.  Would let you put all that functionality in one place, such as the login, profile, logout pages etc...

If you were to add a `member.php` controller you can put all the stuff that you only want to show to logged in users there.  And then in the `__construct` method of that controller you check if the current session is logged in and it covers all methods for that file.

The url schema is this `http://example.com/{controller}/{method}/{args ... }`.  But you can also use urls like this `http://example.com/index.php/{controller}/{method}/{args ... }`.  I'm using Mod Rewrite to allow for the removal of the `index.php` in the URL, so if you don't have that then you have to put `index.php` in the URL ( or remove it by some other means )

**REWRITE_BASE** On my local test server I just place everything in it's own folder as I am to lazy to setup virtual hosts.  So you would want to change this constant, and the matching .htaccess, value to be whatever your sub folder is ( maybe nothing ).  I just left it here for example of how to use it within a sub-folder.

Lastly, this is the `C` in traditional MVC architecture. You should avoid doing what is called "Business logic" in the controllers, you should also avoid outputting HTML directly from the controller (although I did this in the examples).  Instead of outputting the HTML, I would suggest using a template engine like `Blade` or `Twig` there are many of these freely available.  Think of a Controller like the "Glue" that joins the "Model (business logic)" to the "View (template)".  Business logic would be like a User class (uppercase U like a noun, not lowercase as in our user controller) that handles the Database functionality for users.  So instead of putting that code right in the Controller you would build a "User Model" and import that into the controller.  This is the "Right Way" to do it, but of course it adds some complexity up front, but you will find later on the organization of it to far outweigh that in time savings.

**Now some examples**

404 errors (and missed routes):

- `http://example.com/foo` routes to `home::error404()` and outputs `<h3>Error 404 page foo/index not found</h3>`
- `http://example.com/home/foo` routes to `home::error404()` and outputs `<h3>Error 404 page home/foo not found</h3>`

Default Home page:

- `http://example.com/` routes to `home::index()`
- `http://example.com/index.php` routes to `home::index()`
- `http://example.com/home` routes to `home::index()`
- `http://example.com/home/index` routes to `home::index()`
- `http://example.com/home/index/hello` routes to `home::index('hello')`
- `http://example.com/home/index/hello/world` routes to `home::index('hello','world')`

As it stands you have to put the full path in for arguments for home, the above code could be changed to account for this but it has some repercussions for missing pages.  Basically any missing page would become an argument of the controller.  So if you had `http://example.com/user/foo` it would call `user::index('foo')` if that was done.  Of course this too can be accounted for but the complexity starts to stack up.

- `http://example.com/home/otherpage` routes to `home::otherpage()` but issues a warning for missing argument.

  - `http://example.com/home/otherpage/hello` routes to `home::otherpage('hello')`
  - `http://example.com/index.php/home/otherpage/hello` routes to `home::otherpage('hello')`

If you look: `home::index($arg=false)` defines a default, where this method does not. So this method requires an argument.  The rest of this should be pretty self explanatory.

Second Controller user example:

- `http://example.com/user` routes to `user::index()`
- `http://example.com/user/index` routes to `user::index()`
- `http://example.com/user/login` routes to `user::login()`

The rest of this is pretty much the same, I just wanted to show how to organize the controllers by functionally for the site.

I should note that this can handle an unlimited number of arguments following the `{method}` in the url.

Enjoy!

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could write me one. I have been struggling for days with it